# How to declare packed struct (without padding) for LLVM?

Tags: objective-c, c, struct

It's possible to tell GCC it should not use padding for the struct. This is done using `__attribute__((packed))`.

```
typedef struct {

  uint8_t startSymbol;
  uint8_t packetType;
  uint32_t deviceId;
  uint16_t packetCRC;

} PacketData __attribute__((packed));
```

However, newest Xcode uses LLVM and does not recognize the attribute.  How to define packed struct for LLVM?

The full description of the problem might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687981/union-struct-printing-struct-member-of-type-uint32-t-skips-two-bytes-and-prints/13688246#13688246)

**UPDATE**  I'm using Xcode 4.5.1 for iOS which uses Apple LLVM 4.1 compiler. I'm getting "'packed' attribute ignored" warning in Xcode in the code example above.

Comment: Am I missing something or this is a very new feature removal? The last time I checked, clang supported `__attribute__((packed))`...

Comment: clang supports the exact same `__attribute__((packed))` pragma...

Comment: Have no idea :) I'm using Xcode 4.5.1 for iOS which uses Apple LLVM 4.1 compiler.

Comment: @Centurion I found the answer, see the edit.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Did you actually try it? I just tested it on my machine, and `__attribute__((packed))` compiled fine using `clang`.

**Edit:** I got the same warning ("Warning: packed attribute unused") for

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    char c;
} mystruct __attribute__((packed));
```

and in this case `sizeof(mystruct)` was 8.

However,

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    int a;
    char c;
} mystruct;
```

worked just fine, and `sizeof(mystruct)` was 5.

Conclusion: it seems that the attribute needs to preceed the struct label in order to get this working.

Comment: Yes, I did it just now. I'm using Xcode 4.5.1 for iOS which uses Apple LLVM 4.1 compiler. I'm getting "'packed' attribute ignored" warning in Xcode

Comment: @Centurion Then check `sizeof(PacketData)` to see if the warning is moot. Clang on Linux handles the pragma just fine.

Comment: @Centurion Doesn't it mean that it's recognized/supported just not used? Are you actually instantiating the structure anywhere in the code?

Comment: @H2CO3, You just saved my life :) Thanks a lot, your suggestion have worked and now getting correct struct member value. Thanks again :)

Comment: Putting it on the last line works too: "} __attribute__((packed)) mystruct;"

Comment: Putting the attribute at the end applies it to the _typedef_, not the _struct_ itself; that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

You can use preprocessor directive to specify byte alignment for the struct so no padding will be done by the compiler:

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct {
char        t1;
long long   t2;
char        t3;
} struct_size_test;

#pragma options align=reset
```

See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955132/structure-padding-compile-flag/25516440#25516440) question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

clang 3.5 on Linux -

```
typedef struct  __attribute__((packed)) thing1 { int blah; } THING_ONE;
```

worked.

Comment: There were already an answer stating exactly this, why add another?

Comment: including the (name?) in between the ((packed)) and the "{ int blah; }" is different I believe.