# structure padding compile flag

Tags: ios, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, padding

```
typedef struct{
    char        t1;
    long long   t2;
    char        t3;
}struct_size_test;

printf("sizeof(long long)==[%ld]\n", sizeof(long long));
printf("sizeof(char)==[%ld]\n", sizeof(char));
printf("sizeof(struct_size_test)==[%ld]\n", sizeof(struct_size_test));
```

The result of struct_size_test in iOS and in OS X gcc is different.
The result in iOS is

```
sizeof(long long)==[8]
sizeof(char)==[1]
sizeof(struct_size_test)==[24]
```

But the result in OS X gcc is

```
sizeof(long long)==[8]
sizeof(char)==[1]
sizeof(struct_size_test)==[16]
```

I googled this and found some advice that to add "-malign-double" as the gcc compile flag.
But it shows

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-malign-double' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
```

Any idea how to sync the structure padding for iOS and OS X?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you trying to do here? If you are trying to play with structure packing then it is really likely that you are attempting something very misguided or stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer should be that you most certainly don't want to do this.

You could try nneonneo's solution or add `__attribute__((packed))` to your structs to make the structs the same size on both OS X and iOS but keep in mind this is a compiler specific feature and will make your code less portable

Furthermore, if you did change the padding, your program would likely crash or run less efficiently on either architectures (especially iOS/ARM) due to alignment requirements not being met. Some ARM architectures (unsure about iDevices) won't allow unaligned reads/writes and will outright crash if not run slower (since two memory reads are required instead of one).

A workaround might be to use the highest common alignment (appears to be 8), which would simply take a bit more space. But this is still hacky and non-portable.

Why are you trying to do this anyway?

Edit: nneonneo's answer probably should look like this:

```
typedef struct{
    char        t1 __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
    long long   t2 __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
    char        t3 __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
} struct_size_test;
```

Comment: No, I can not use __attribute__((packed)), the structure size must be exactly the same as what iOS shows. The structure is already defined for many team member's use. So the structure can not be changed.

Comment: Why does it have to be a specific size? Are you using the struct in assembly code or something?

Comment: Use it for TCP communication, so one it's on two different platforms. And the TX platform is fixed, we can not changed it.

Comment: I'd reckon it's better to have a portable serializing and serializing routine that takes raw bytes and converts it into the internal representation of that architecture instead of trying to use struct hacks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use preprocessor directive to specify byte alignment for the struct so no padding will be done by the compiler:

`#pragma pack(1)`

`typedef struct{`
`char        t1;`
`long long   t2;`
`char        t3;`
`}struct_size_test;`

`#pragma options align=reset`

If the structure is defined in a header file that cannot be changed, say test.h:

`//test.h`
`typedef struct{`
`char        t1;`
`long long   t2;`
`char        t3;`
`}struct_size_test;`

When you include test.h, you can do this:

`#pragma pack(1)`
`#include test.h`
`#pragma options align=reset`

I have used this method in my own code.

Keep in mind the above solution is really not a compiler flag but a preprocessor directive that has the same effect as you have requested. Hope this helps.

Comment: strictly speaking this is not a preprocessor directive, because this particular one is ignored by the preprocessor and is instead interpreted by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an explicit type attribute to control the structure alignment:

```
typedef struct{
    char        t1;
    long long   t2;
    char        t3;
} struct_size_test __attribute__ ((aligned (8))); // aligned(8) = 8-byte alignment
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick advice, but it still shows sizeof(struct_size_test)==[16]. Very strange!

Comment: I think the alignment attribute should go to the individual members.

Comment: @tangrs Oh great! I just saw this. You are correct, the alignment attribute should go to the individual members. Thanks for the help!
Do you have any idea why '-malign-double' flag does not work?

Comment: Maybe it's a GCC specific flag