# Assign a struct to an int value in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, struct

I think I would like to pack a section index and a row index together into an int and assign the result to the tag property of a UIView. I thought I could do it like this but it doesn’t work:

```
typedef struct
{
    int16_t section;
    int16_t row;
} SecRow;

SecRow sr = {2,3};
UIView* aview = [[UIView alloc] init];
[aview setTag:sr];//Error - Sending ‘SecRow’ to parameter of incompatible type ’NSInteger’ (aka ‘int’)
or
[aview setTag:(int32_t)sr];//Error - Operand of type ‘SecRow’ where arithmetic or pointer type is required
```

I realize this would limit maximum values for section and row but I think 16 bit should be enough. In the past I would simply multiply section by 1000 or 10000 and add it to row, but I’d like to come up with the least limiting way of doing this. I would also like to avoid manipulating bit fields if I can.

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you doing ? You can't assign struct to int. You can typecast struct to int like that. So your previous approach was good in my opinion. Or subclass UIView and declare a `SecRow` property and assign the value to it.

Comment: `*((int32_t *)&sr)` should do the trick.

Comment: I am working with a UICollectionView. Sometimes an event happens in a cell and I need to know who the cell's header is. I can assign the cell's row to its tag when I create the cell, but I'd like for the cell to know who its section is as well.

Comment: The right way to do it is to use C shift and mask operations to combine your two values into a single int.  It's very elementary C stuff which you should already know how to do.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès -- You're assuming that the struct is packed.  Is that the default for the Objective-C compiler??

Comment: See this for struct packing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688625/how-to-declare-packed-struct-without-padding-for-llvm

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - So apparently you need to specify `__attribute__((packed))`?  I think using shift/mask is probably safer and more robust.

Comment: Use a custom cell type (class) and add any additional properties that you need. Besides that, I don't get the problem because didSelectRowAtIndexPath, etc., all provide an NSIndexPath which includes row and section.

Comment: @HotLicks yes but you need to define some operators, to pack and unpack. I have no preference for one or the other. Both are valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `union`:

```
typedef union {
  struct {
    int16_t section;
    int16_t row;
  } fields;
  int32_t bits;
} SecRow;
```

Then `sr.bits`. It does make your assignment a little longer:

```
SecRow sr = { .fields.section = 2, .fields.row = 3 };
```

Comment: This looks close. I get an error on the second typedef: "Type name does not allow storage class to be specified".

Comment: The second typedef was a typo. ;)