# How do we force compiler not to have structure padding? Please explain

Tags: c

How do we force compilers not to have structure padding?Please explain.

Comment: Use the packed attribute, see similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473189/what-is-a-packed-structure-in-c

Answer (score 2):

The post [What is a "packed" structure in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473189/what-is-a-packed-structure-in-c) addresses how to avoid padding when using gcc.

```
struct foo __attribute__((__packed__)) 
{
   ...
};
```

The method is same for `clang`. See [How to declare packed struct (without padding) for LLVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688625/how-to-declare-packed-struct-without-padding-for-llvm).

The post at [Locally disable padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933707/locally-disable-padding) addresses how to avoid padding when using MS Visual Studio.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct foo
{ 
   ...
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```